# simple django class-based generic views: am I doing it right?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-generic-views

I am working on a simple "to do list" app in django (two models: List and Item). Trying to learn and make use of class-based generic views. I have the following three display views working, but am requesting a quick code review to see if there's anything I can do to improve my usage/understanding of django's ListView and DetailView before I move on to creating, updating and deleting. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
# class-based generic views for my lists, a list's items, and item detail...
class MyListsView(ListView):
    """Display My Lists"""
    template_name = 'cmv_app/my_lists.html'
    context_object_name = 'my_lists'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # override get_queryset() to filter in only lists belonging to the current user,
        # eliminating the need to define a model in this class.
        return List.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('-last_modified')

    # override dispatch to decorate this view with login_required
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyListsView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)


class ListItemsView(ListView):
    """Display a list's items"""
    template_name = 'cmv_app/list_items.html'
    context_object_name = 'list_items'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get a particular list's items
        items = Item.objects.filter(list=self.kwargs['list_id']).order_by('-created_date')
        return items

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(ListItemsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add the list, needed for the template to lookup urls for the item detail page
        context['list'] = self.list
        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.list = get_object_or_404(List, pk=kwargs['list_id'])
        # this is a security check: a user can only access his own lists 
        # (else raise PermissionDenied)
        request = list_valid_for_user(request, self.list) 
        return super(ListItemsView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    """Show detail for one item"""
    template_name = 'cmv_app/item_detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.item

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # fetching list and item in here instead of in get_object() in order to implement
        # security checks
        self.list = get_object_or_404(List, pk=kwargs['list_id'])
        self.item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=kwargs['item_id'])
        # user can only access his lists (else raise PermissionDenied)
        request = list_valid_for_user(request, self.list) 
        # item must be associated with the specified list (else raise PermissionDenied)
        request = item_valid_for_list(request, self.item, self.list)
        return super(ItemDetailView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in the elements needed for the template to construct url for link to list
        context['list'] = self.list
        return context
```

Comment: I am particularly concerned about adding business logic in dispatch(). It works but I suspect there's a better / more "standard" way?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Reviewing Code and should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oops, thanks Maxime. I did not know about the codereview.stackexchange.com. I'll try there.

Answer (score 1):

For example, for the `ListItemsViews`, in your dispatch only do:

```
self.list = kwargs['list']
self.list_id = kwargs['list_id']
```

Then, this goes to `get_context_data`:

```
self.list = get_object_or_404(List, pk=self.list_id)
```

and this goes to `get_queryset`:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(list=self.list_id).order_by('-created_date')
```